# Flutter bloc doesn't trigger the loading screen the second time when I click the submit button the second time after I close it if no state change

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

the loading screen is popped when response are fetched, but when no data are fetched the loading screen page continues to show. when I close it and click the submit button the second time, the loading screen does not show. I am using flutter bloc. here is my codes

```
the event class
 class Login extends SignInEvent{
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [];

  final String userName;
  final String password;
  final String pin;

   Login(this.userName,this.password,this.pin, ) :super([userName,password,pin]);

 }

the bloc 
     if (event is Login) {
     yield Loading();
  final login = await loginUser(event.userName, event.password, event.pin);
  yield Loaded(login);
  print(login);
}
}

the state

 class Loading extends SignInState{
 @override
 // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [];

  }

  class Loaded extends SignInState{
  final Map response;
  Loaded(this.response):super();
   @override
   // TODO: implement props
   List<Object?> get props => [response];

   }
```

The Ui code. Updated the question adding the UI code

```
  Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => loginBloc,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: BlocListener<SignInBloc, SignInState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          // TODO: implement listener}
          if(state is Loading){
            loading.showAlertDialog(context);
          }
          if (state is Loaded) {
            if(state.response["status"] == "err") {
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
              response.openBottomSheet(context, 
            state.response["message"]);
            }
            else {
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
              Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SubProfile()),);
            }
          }
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<SignInBloc, SignInState>(
          bloc: loginBloc,
          builder: (context, SignInState state) {
            if(state is SignInInitial){
              return LoginPageWidget();
            }
            if (state is Loading) {

            }
            if (state is Loaded) {
              print('Loaded');
            }
           return LoginPageWidget();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: can you please share you'r ui code ?

Comment: I have added the UI code as requested

Comment: could you please add loading.showAlertDialog(context); in your BlocBuilder too, for loading condition. let me know about the result.

Comment: It will exhibit the same behavior because I have used equatable. To triggger a state back to back, equatable should not be used

Comment: if you can please set you'r code in github, so i can develop it and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I used equatable so if no state changes, there will be no rebuild so the second yield will be ignored.
To trigger trigger a state back to back like my case, equatable should not be used

Comment: You used equatable yet you didn’t add the variables to your props list, so it’s basically useless in this context

Comment: But there is no variable attached to the loading state class in my code